# Function to remove unwanted chars - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, chars

After a bit of research I found out how to remove a series of unwanted characters from a string. I am planning on throwing this in a function and calling it when needed.

However usually when I program or code something I just want it to work rather than work well so I was wondering if you SQL Server experts out there see anything that could make the code more elegant and if you can spot any potential SQL injection issues:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpMNHArrayOfChars') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpMNHArrayOfChars
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ExcludedChars') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ExcludedChars
    GO

DECLARE @SomeString VARCHAR(300);
SET @SomeString = 'Fluffy=the_rab bit_';

DECLARE @Count INT;
SET @Count = 0;

DECLARE @Len INT;
SET @Len = LEN(@SomeString);

DECLARE @CharVal VARCHAR;
DECLARE @CharPos INT;

--Create a table for each char in the string
CREATE TABLE #tmpMNHArrayOfChars (CharPos INT, CharVal VARCHAR)

WHILE @Count <= @Len 
BEGIN
    SET @CharVal = RIGHT(LEFT(@SomeString, @Count),1)

    INSERT INTO #tmpMNHArrayOfChars (CharPos, CharVal) VALUES (@Count, @CharVal)

    SET @Count = @Count + 1;
END

-- Set up Tmp table of excluded chars
CREATE TABLE #ExcludedChars
(
    CharId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CharString VARCHAR(12)
)
INSERT INTO #ExcludedChars (CharId, CharString)
VALUES
    (001, '!'),
    (002, '£'),
    (003, '$'),
    (004, '%'),
    (005, '^'),
    (006, '&'),
    (007, '*'),
    (008, '('),
    (009, ')'),
    (010, '_'),
    (011, '+'),
    (012, '='),
    (013, '@'),
    (014, '~'),
    (015, '#'),
    (016, '\'),
    (017, '/'),
    (018, '|'),
    (019, '{'),
    (020, '}'),
    (021, '['),
    (022, ']'),
    (023, '<'),
    (024, '>'),
    (025, '.'),
    (026, ','),
    (027, '¬')

--Compare two tables and remove uneeded chars
DECLARE @SomeInt INT
DECLARE @SomeCount INT

DELETE SC FROM #tmpMNHArrayOfChars SC
CROSS JOIN #ExcludedChars EC WHERE SC.CharVal=EC.CharString 

SELECT * FROM #tmpMNHArrayOfChars SC
```

Comment: expedted output should be

Comment: Performance wise, I don't think there's a better way than nested `REPLACE` statements I'm afraid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Character mapping / search and replace character by character in SQL Server 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070643/character-mapping-search-and-replace-character-by-character-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Thanks guys its all a learning experience, thanks for the info guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @SomeString VARCHAR(300);
    SET @SomeString = 'Fluffy=the_rab bit_';
    SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR,
        (SELECT SUBSTRING(@SomeString,sv.number,1) FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS sv 
        WHERE  sv.type='P' AND sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@SomeString)
        AND  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM #ExcludedChars AS e WHERE e.CharString= SUBSTRING(@SomeString,sv.number,1))
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
    )
```

Comment: Note that this will only support strings with at most 2047 characters by default

Comment: Thanks for this! Looking into both my bad solution and your much cleaner version I've found I cant put this into a function anyway as this uses temp tables which seems to not be allowed.