# How to replace characters based on a replacement table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table that has the following columns:

```
find char(1)
replace varchar(2)
```

And some data within it is:

```
find replace
------------
ä    ae
ö    oe
ü    ue
ß    ss
```

I have a stored procedure that generates XML content (around 30MB) based on 60000+ rows. The content is based on various tables, and for example, one table contains the customer name. This column might contain one or more of the replaceable characters above.

How can I write a function that replaces characters of a string (passed as parameter) by using the above table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Character mapping / search and replace character by character in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070643/character-mapping-search-and-replace-character-by-character-in-sql-server-2008).

Comment: @Han Might work. In my case, which collaction should I use on the `find` column?

Answer (score 1):

This following script will guide you towards you desired result. Please adjust table and column names as per your Lookup table-

```
DECLARE @LookUp TABLE(
    find VARCHAR(MAX),
    replace VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO @LookUp (find,replace) 
VALUES
('ä','ae'),
('ö','oe'),
('ü','ue'),
('ß','ss')


DECLARE @testVal VARCHAR(100)
SET @testVal = 'ä Test ö Test2 ü Test3 ß Test4'
SELECT @testVal = REPLACE(@testVal, find, replace) FROM (SELECT find,replace FROM  @LookUp) list
SELECT @testVal;
```